# a metric on the space of probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can I define on the space of probability measure on some complete separable metric space the following metric?

$d_1(\mu, \nu)=\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}=\frac{1}{2}\sup\limits_{f: X\to [-1.1]}[\int f d\mu -\int f d\nu]$ (Total Variation Norm, distance)?

Now, is that metric is equivalent to the following one?

$d_2(\mu, \nu)=\sup\limits_{f\in A}[\int f d\mu -\int f d\nu]$ where
$A=\{f: X\to \mathbb R: |f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|\}$ and $f$ is measurable.

Thanks for confirming.

Somewhat inspired from this question 
[Two notions of total variation norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852646/two-notions-of-total-variation-norms)

Comment: The second metric is a known duality result by Kantorovich, which states roughly that the metric is equivalent to the $1$-Wasserstein metric. The Wasserstein metric is equivalent to weak convergence, which is _not_ equivalent to convergence in total variation.

Comment: an example to disprove your last statement? or intuition

Comment: Can you give your two metrics different names, like $d_1, d_2$?  It's confusing to call them both $d$.  And in the definition of the first one, what's the set $A$ over which you are taking the supremum?  If it's the same set $A$ as in $d_2$, then $d_1$ is not the total variation metric.

Comment: @Marso For intuition, in total variation the supremum is taking over bounded measurable functions, whereas in weak convergence we take either bounded (uniformly) continuous functions or bounded Lipschitz functions (Portmanteau theorem). Thus weak convergence is definitely weaker than TV. For a counterexample, $\mu_n = \delta_{1/n}$ on $\Bbb R$ converges weakly to $\delta_0$, but choosing any bounded function $f$ with a discontinuity at $0$ like $f(x) = 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ we get
$$
\|\mu_n - \delta_0\|_{TV} \geq |f(1/n)-f(0)| = 1
$$
for all $n$.

Comment: Could you please write one line to explain to me what does it mean by $\mu_n\to \delta_0$ weakly? Does it mean for any continuous function f on real, $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \mu_n(dx)\to \int_{\mathbb R}  f(x) \delta_0(dx)$?

Comment: Yes it means that but for bounded continuous functions, not just continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total variation distance is a metric on the space of all complex Borel measures and its restriction to the class of probability measures is a nice complete metric. [It is not separable in general].