# Equality between expressions for total variation distance between two discrete probability distributions.

Tags: probability-theory, total-variation

I found an excellent answer to a more general form of this question here: [Two notions of total variation norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852646/two-notions-of-total-variation-norms) but it is a bit more sophisticated than what I am looking for. My question

> Let $X,Y$ be positive integer valued random variables. Then $$d_{\mathrm{TV}}(X,Y) = \frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\mathbb P(X=k)-\mathbb P(Y=k)| = \sup_{A\subset\mathbb R}|\mathbb P(X\in A) - \mathbb P(Y\in A)|. $$

I do not see how this equality holds. In particular the factor of $\frac12$ is throwing me off. How can we see that this sum is proportional to this supremum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note
$$P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A) = \sum_{k \in A} (P(X = k) - P(Y = k))$$
Additionally,
$$P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A) = P(Y \in A^c) - P(X \in A^c) = \sum_{k \in A^c} (P(Y = k) - P(X = k))$$

Choosing $A = \{k : P(X = k) \ge P(Y = k)\}$ and summing the above two equations yields
$$2(P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A))
= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty |P(X = k) - P(Y = k)|.$$
The left-hand side is nonnegative because the right-hand side is nonnegative, so you can take the absolute value of the left-hand side without changing the equality.

Finally, note that this choice of $A$ maximizes the expression in the supremum.

Comment: Very clever, thank you! I should have figured from the $\sup_{A\subset \mathbb R}$ that it had to do with choosing the $k$ that maximize the expression.